# Mi archivo de rutas flutter me marca un problema

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, vscode

Mis Navigator.pushNamed me marcan un error al hacer Tap, funcionaba bien pero cambie de computadora y ya no funciona, tengo las rutas en un archivo .dart que hace las funciones de cambiar de pantallas
Rutas.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Pages
import 'package:califood/src/features/presentation/welcome_page/View/Welcome_page.dart';
import 'package:califood/src/features/presentation/forgot_pass_page/View/forgot_password.dart';
import 'package:califood/src/features/presentation/register_1_page/View/register_1.dart';
import 'package:califood/src/features/presentation/tabs/tabs_page.dart';

final routes = <String, WidgetBuilder> {
  'welcome' : (BuildContext context) => WelcomePage(),
  'forgot-password' :(BuildContext context) => ForgotPassword(),
  'registro' : (BuildContext context) => Registro(),
  'tabs' : (BuildContext context) => TabsPage(),
};
```

Este es mi pagina principal con los botones para cambiar de pantallas
Home.dart

```
Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 130.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'Password'); //Ruta para cambiar hacia forgot_password.dart
            },
           child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
             child: Text(
               '¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?',
                 style: TextStyle(
                 color: Colors.black,
                 fontFamily: "Poppins",
                 fontSize: 14.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

ForgotPassword.dart tiene la class ForgotePassword

El error que me genera es este: No movi nada de los Widgets que vienen por defecto en flutter

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("Password", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate
this route.
Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
 1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
 2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
 3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
 4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _WidgetsAppState._onUnknownRoute.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/app.dart:1175
#1      _WidgetsAppState._onUnknownRoute
package:flutter/…/widgets/app.dart:1190
#2      NavigatorState._routeNamed
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:3388
#3      NavigatorState.pushNamed
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:3425
#4      Navigator.pushNamed
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:1587
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#3f3cc
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    state: possible
    won arena
    finalPosition: Offset(171.7, 366.3)
    finalLocalPosition: Offset(20.2, 17.3)
    button: 1
    sent tap down
```

Comment: La ruta la tienes nombrada como "forgot-password" y estás intentanto navegar a "Password" y claro, no la encuentra. Saludos, espero ayudarte.

Comment: Cambie la ruta 
```
final routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
  'welcome': (BuildContext context) => WelcomePage(),
  'Password': (BuildContext context) => ForgotePassword(),
  'registro': (BuildContext context) => Registro(),
  'tabs': (BuildContext context) => TabsPage(),
};
```
Me sale el mismo error
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("Password", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Comment: Agregaste las rutas en el MaterialApp? en tu main.dart debes tener algo similar a esto: MaterialApp()( routes:routes )